# Storing images in Arraylist of Images in Android

Tags: android, image, arraylist, bitmap, server

How to store images retrieved from server in Array list of Bitmap ?
I have tried but the arraylist showing null values.

Following code to get image from server:-

```html
ParseQuery<ParseObject> imgquery = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("ChatRecords");
imgquery.getInBackground(ChatRecordObjectID, new GetCallback<ParseObject>() 
{       
 @Override
 public void done(ParseObject object,ParseException e) 
 {
  System.out.println("in 2nd done:"+time2); 
  ParseFile fileObject = (ParseFile) object.get("ImageMessage");
    fileObject.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() 
    {
     @Override
     public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e)
     {
      if (e == null) 
      {
      bmp= BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0,data.length);
      imageBitmap.add(bmp);
      }
      else 
      {
     Log.d("test","There was a problem downloading the data.");     }
   }
  });
 }
});

Following Code to retrieve image in array list :-

for(int i=0;i<imageBitmap.size();i++)
{
 ImageView imageView = new ImageView(CurrentUserActivity.this);
 imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.msgrecv);
 imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
 imageView.setMaxHeight(150);
 imageView.setMaxWidth(inScrollViewLeft.getLayoutParams().width);
 imageView.requestLayout();
 imageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap.get(i));
 inScrollViewLeft.addView(imageView);
 }
```

Error is :

```
04-28 09:57:08.280: E/AndroidRuntime(2769): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
04-28 09:57:08.280: E/AndroidRuntime(2769): at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
```

Comment: Post the code that you use to create the list, and add the bitmaps.

Comment: store image in memory have the path of the images in the list its better. Do post your code

Answer (score 0):

Add your bitmap object into `ArratList` e.g.

```
ArrayList<Bitmap> images = new ArrayList<>();
images.add(downlaodedBitmap);
```

Comment: while retrieving from arraylist it is giving Error is : 04-28 09:57:08.280: E/AndroidRuntime(2769): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0 04-28 09:57:08.280: E/AndroidRuntime(2769): at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)

Comment: I can't see your imageBitmap list instantiation!
use imageBitmap = new ArrayList<>(); somewhere. or it seems your code that inserts the bitmaps is not reachable.

Comment: I have instantiated the arraylist.

Comment: remove "if (e == null) " and try again

Answer (score 0):

I made following changes in the above code, sometimes the images are set sequentially and sometimes not.please check the code and let me know the changes :

```html
public void searchChatRecord()
 {
  k=0;
    
  ParseQuery<ParseObject> pq = ParseQuery.getQuery("ChatRecords");
  pq.whereNotEqualTo("objectId", null);
  pq.orderByAscending("createdAt");
  pq.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

  @Override
  public void done(List<ParseObject> chatObjects, ParseException e) {
    
   if(e == null)
   { 
    if(chatObjects.size()>0)
    { 
    System.out.println("chatObjects.size() : "+chatObjects.size());
     for(int i =0;i<chatObjects.size();i++)
     { 
      k++;
      if(chatObjects.get(i).getString("SenderObjectID").equals(currentUser.getObjectId()) && chatObjects.get(i).getString("RecieverObjectID").equals(recieverObjectID))
      {
       addImg.add("S2R");
       ChatRecordObjectID = chatObjects.get(i).getObjectId();
       chatID.add(ChatRecordObjectID);
       time1=chatObjects.get(i).getString("date_time"); // ..po.getString("date_time");    
       System.out.println("in 1st :"+time1);
       time.add(time1);
      }
      else 
      if(chatObjects.get(i).getString("SenderObjectID").equals(recieverObjectID) && chatObjects.get(i).getString("RecieverObjectID").equals(currentUser.getObjectId()))
      {
       addImg.add("R2S");
       ChatRecordObjectID =chatObjects.get(i).getObjectId();
       chatID.add(ChatRecordObjectID);
       time2= chatObjects.get(i).getString("date_time");
       time.add(time2);
       System.out.println("in 2nd :"+time2);        
       
      }
     
        
     if(k==chatObjects.size())
     {
      System.out.println(k);
      for(int j=0;j<addImg.size();j++)
      {
       
       if(addImg.get(j).equals("S2R"))
       {
        userToReciever(chatID.get(j), time.get(j));
       }
       else
       if(addImg.get(j).equals("R2S"))
       {
        recieverToUser(chatID.get(j), time.get(j));
       }
      }
     }
    }
    }
    else
    {
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No chat records", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
   }
  }
 });
 } 
 
 public void userToReciever(String id,final String msgTime)
 {
  ParseQuery<ParseObject> imgquery = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("ChatRecords");
  imgquery.getInBackground(id, new GetCallback<ParseObject>() 
  {
   @Override
   public void done(ParseObject object,ParseException e) 
   {
    System.out.println("in 1st done:"+msgTime); 
    ParseFile fileObject = (ParseFile) object.get("ImageMessage");
    fileObject.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() 
    {
     @Override
     public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e)
     {
      if (e == null) 
      {
       Log.d("test","We've got data in data.");
       bmp= BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0,data.length);
                   
       TextView t = new TextView(CurrentUserActivity.this);
       t.setPadding(10,50, 0, 2);
       t.setText("me"+"   "+msgTime);
       ImageView imageView = new ImageView(CurrentUserActivity.this);
       imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shape);
       imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
       imageView.setMaxHeight(150);
       imageView.setMaxWidth(inScrollViewLeft.getLayoutParams().width);
       imageView.requestLayout();
       imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
       inScrollViewLeft.addView(t);
       inScrollViewLeft.addView(imageView);
       
      }
      else 
      {
        Log.d("test","There was a problem downloading the data.");
      }
     }
    });
   }
    
  });
 }
 
 
 public void recieverToUser(String id,final String msgTime) {
  
  ParseQuery<ParseObject> imgquery = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("ChatRecords");
  imgquery.getInBackground(id, new GetCallback<ParseObject>() 
  {
   @Override
   public void done(ParseObject object,ParseException e) 
   {
    System.out.println("in 2nd done:"+msgTime); 
    ParseFile fileObject = (ParseFile) object.get("ImageMessage");
    fileObject.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() 
    {
     @Override
     public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e)
     {
      if (e == null) 
      {
      Log.d("test","We've got data in data.");
      bmp= BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0,data.length);
                  
       TextView t = new TextView(CurrentUserActivity.this);
       t.setPadding(10,50, 0, 2);
       t.setText("me"+"   "+msgTime);
       ImageView imageView = new ImageView(CurrentUserActivity.this);
       imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.msgrecv);
       imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
       imageView.setMaxHeight(150);
       imageView.setMaxWidth(inScrollViewLeft.getLayoutParams().width);
       imageView.requestLayout();
       imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
       inScrollViewLeft.addView(t);
       inScrollViewLeft.addView(imageView);
       
      }
      else 
      {
        Log.d("test","There was a problem downloading the data.");
      }
     }
    });
   }
    
  });
  
 }
```